# Best way to setup segmented buying by weight and quantity?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, discount, tierprice, pricing

I am looking for some help on how to allow customers to purchase by weight and quantity and offer a discount the more they buy. For example say we have two products, Almonds SKU1 and Almonds SKU2. What is the best way to implement the following:

**Almonds SKU1**

1kg for $20

4 x 1kg for $76

8 x 1kg for $144

etc..

**Almonds SKU2**

25kg for $375

etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can set different prices based on the quantity purchased. That is called "Tier Price" in Magento (edit the product, then click on the "Prices" tab)

[image]

Comment: That wouldn't cater for the different weights though. I don't really want to create a product for each weight. I want the customer to choose a weight and then a quantity for that weight. based on this discounts are applied. I am surprised there isn't a straightforward way to do this as this seems like quite a normal situation for E-Commerce. Maybe I am missing something.